# PHP : placeholder not working for identifier in pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I am putting a placeholder for an identifier, and to sanitize the table variable I have done:

```
$table = "users";
$table = "`".str_replace("`","``",$table)."`";
```

and done this to run my query:

```
$stmt = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->execute([$table, "irfan"]);
```

This is the error I am receiving:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''`users`' WHERE username = 'irfan''

Comment: You can't use `?` in table names

Comment: You can't bind table or column names, only values.

Comment: @Qirel . Yes, I know that, so thats why I have sanitized the variable for it to fit in. Isn't that possible?

Comment: You haven't really sanitized it. It should be whitelisted, you can't bind it at all.

Comment: No it's not a data type `PDO` prepared only handles data.

Comment: Then how do I whitelist it?

Comment: Most likely you just don't need it. There is no use case where you need a query like this.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm following your tutorial https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#why

Comment: @IrfanSindhi My tutorial is on how to use PDO, not on the basic PHP/mysql architecture. if your query is not an artificial sketch but a real one, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: why do you think you need a query like this?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not for any specific purpose. I was just playing around with placeholders.

Comment: Well now you know that you cannot use placeholders for the table names.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes, I do. Thank you.